# Terraria for iOS keeps crashing in my iPhone 4s

Tags: technical-issues, terraria-mobile

So sometimes when I'm bored I go onto my phone and play a $5 game named terraria. It's fun but I have some complaints. I'm not sure if this happens for everyone or if it's just my phone, but a lot of the time I'm brought back to my home screen. This gets annoying because sometimes it would happen at a bad time because I'm fighting a boss or something. And when I go back in to the game all the things that I've placed or built like houses and rooms I use teleporters to get to and the wire that I spent like 3-4 mins tops becomes a huge waste of time since it would all be gone by the time I go back. Mind you I have a crappy battery iPhone 4S so it might just be my phone. How could I fix this? Can You help me?

Comment: Contact Re-Logic. Make sure to include as much info as possible. If it's an app bug, we can't help.

Comment: Also this ONLY happens for terraria.

Comment: @Alex may I ask how I could contact re-logic?

Comment: There [Official Site](https://re-logic.com) has there contact email

Comment: An incident where the application exits and returns to the home screen is called "crash", as we call spontaneous exiting of a Windows PC program. I think we need more details to answer to a frequent crash incident. I suppose out-of-memory issues, but if that is the case, we could really do nothing but to say typical things like "kill any other applications before running Terraria," since upgrading your phone is probably not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your iPhone 4S is damaged and/or does not have enough RAM to run Terraria.

You should try closing the background applications, closing AirShou(if you use it), and reinstalling the Terraria app.

Comment: If it didn't have enough RAM it would crash on startup

Comment: @Alex Nope. It loads temporary stats into memory. If it's too much, the app burps.

Comment: if it doesn't have enough ram it wouldn't allow you to get the app

Comment: @Alex, that doesnt make any sense at all. You can have the RAM when you download the app, and not have it when you go to run it. I think you are confusing RAM for hard drive/ storage memory.